# Как при помощи регулярных выражений оставить строки определенного формата

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть вот у меня такая строка

```
7(917) 123-16-23 7(927) 123-14-11 -     -      5
```

как в питоне при помощи регулярных выражений можно оставить только те цифры которые попадают под такой шаблон?
(цифра, скобка, цифра, цифра, цифра, скобка, пробел, цифра....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = "7(917) 123-16-23 7(927) 123-14-11"

print(re.findall(r'\d\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d\d-\d\d', text))
# ['7(917) 123-16-23', '7(927) 123-14-11']
```

Если несколько шаблонов разделяйте их вертикальной чертой, пример:

```
pattern = r'\d\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d\d-\d\d|\+\d \d{3} \d{3}-\d\d-\d\d'
text = "7(917) 123-16-23 +7 927 123-14-11 7(927) 123-14-11"

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
# ['7(917) 123-16-23', '+7 927 123-14-11', '7(927) 123-14-11']
```

Comment: а если нужно использовать несколько шаблонов, как правильно записать?

Comment: @demo `(\d\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d\d-\d\d|другой шаблон)` ну лучше бы отредактировать вопрос и полностью описать задачу по захвату regex

Comment: @demo, такое нужно в вопросе описывать заранее :) Т.к. технически на ваш вопрос я уже ответил :) А так, PotroNik правильно написал, если несколько шаблонов, то разделяйте их через `|` (вертикальную черту), я добавлю пример